# How do you display time after threads complete in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I need to simulate the time it takes for multiple customers to use a changing room. My inputs are number of changing rooms, number of customers, and number of items(an input of 0 here picks a random number of items for each customer). If a customer is waiting they will enter when the other leaves. I need to report the total number of items and the overall time it takes for all customers.

Requirements:
1. A constructor that sets the number of rooms.
2. A semaphore to control access to the rooms.
3. A requestRoom method that waits and gains access to the room.
4. A customer will be implemented as a thread.
5. Each customer will have 1-6 items that take 1-3 minutes to try on.
6. A scenario class will take the number of rooms and customers

The code below allows customers to begin trying on their items and once completed leave the room. If there are more customers than rooms, extra customers will wait until a room opens. I can not display the time that it takes for the overall process though. The time will print 0 before any of the threads run. I have tried using an executorservice to shutdown and await termination where cust.start() is. This allows for a timer to print once done but does not allow for multiple customers to try their items on at the same time. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;


public class IT481_Norman_Unit6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numRooms =3;
        int numCus;
        int numItems =3;
        String scenario;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Input the number of dressing rooms for this scenario: ");
        int numRooms = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Input the number of customers for this scenario: ");
        int numCus = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Input the number of items each customer has for this scenario \n (a value of 0 will pick a random number): ");
        int numItems = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        input.close();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Here are the results for secenario " + scenario + ".");
        System.out.println("This scenario has " + numCus + " customers.");
        System.out.println("This scenario has " + numRooms + " rooms.");

        if (numItems != 0)
            System.out.println("Total number of items: " + numCus * numItems);
        else
            System.out.println("This scenario is using a random number of items. ");

        System.out.println("");

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        Scenario.scenario(numRooms, numCus, numItems);

        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long totalTime;

        totalTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
        System.out.println("Total time passed:" + totalTime + " seconds.");
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

class Customer { 

    private final static Random NumTimeGen = new Random();
    private static int timeMin = 1;
    private static int timeMax = 3;
    public int time = 0;
    public static Thread cust;

    public Customer(Semaphore roomAvail, int items, int customer) {

        cust = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                int numOfItems;
                if (items == 0) 
                    numOfItems = new Random().nextInt(6-1+1) + 1 ;
                else
                    numOfItems = items;

                System.out.println("Customer " + (customer + 1) + " has " + numOfItems + " items.");

                try{

                    roomAvail.acquire();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println( "received interuptedexception" );
                }
                System.out.println("Customer " + (customer + 1) + " got a room.");
                for(int j = 1; j <= numOfItems; j++) {
                    Instant start = Instant.now();

                    try {
                        int sleepTime = NumTimeGen.nextInt(timeMax*60*1000/10/30-timeMin*60*1000/10/30) + timeMin*60*1000/10/30;

                        time = time + sleepTime;
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

                    } 

                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Instant finish = Instant.now();

                    long timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis();
                    System.out.println("Customer " + (customer + 1) + " is trying on clothing item Number " + j + " ,time spent: " + timeElapsed);
                }
                roomAvail.release();
                System.out.println("Customer " + (customer + 1) + " left.");

            }
        });
        cust.start();
    }

}

class Scenario {

    public static void scenario(int rooms, int customers, int items) {
        DressingRooms dressingRooms = new DressingRooms(rooms);
        Semaphore availableRooms = dressingRooms.numOfRooms;

        for (int i=0; i < customers; i++) {
            DressingRooms.requestRoom(availableRooms, i, items);
        }
    }
}

class DressingRooms {

    Semaphore numOfRooms;

    public DressingRooms() {
        numOfRooms = new Semaphore(3);
    }

    public DressingRooms(int rooms) {
        numOfRooms = new Semaphore(rooms);
    }

    public static synchronized void requestRoom(Semaphore totalRooms, int custNum, int items) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(totalRooms, items, custNum);

    }
}
```